# Vue JS/ superagent - TypeError: fn is not a function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, superagent

I'm using super agent for HTTP request and I'm trying to use superagent-intercept to catch HTTP requests in order to manage errors and necessary redirections.

When a componant is mounted I call an action from Vuex :

```
GLOBAL_DATA({commit, state}) {
    forms_store.get(null,  (result) => {
        commit('SET_FORMS', result)
    });
}
```

Which call :

```
forms.get = function(root, cb) {
  request
  .get(`${api}/forms/name/FORM`)
  .use(interceptor.auth)
  .use(nocache)
  .withCredentials()
  .set('Accept', 'application/json')
  .end(function(err, res) {
 if (res.body.status === 'success') {
       cb(res.body.data.forms, root)
    } else if (common.token(res)) {
      common.cb(root);
    } else {
      console.log("error");
    }
  });
};
```

Considering :

```
interceptor.auth = require('superagent-intercept')((error, results) => {
        // Error handling .. 
});
```

But I have an error in GLOBAL_DATA :

> TypeError: fn is not a function

I think something is overridden at some point but I can't figure out how to fix it.

Edit :

I changed the syntax of the first function but I still have the same error :

```
GLOBAL_DATA : (context) => {
    forms_store.get(null,  (result) => {
        context.commit('SET_FORMS', result)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the action like this:

```
GLOBAL_DATA: (commit, state) => {
    forms_store.get(null,  (result) => {
        commit('SET_FORMS', result)
    });
}
```

Comment: I edited my code and the post, but I still have the very same error. Do you have any idea what's going on ?